# Dynamics AX 7 Grid line defaulting

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7

I am creating a new grid in AX 7. Does anybody know how to prevent the grid from creating a "default line"?

Here is what it looks like when I open the form with an empty grid:
[image: Empty form with default line]

Here is what I would like it to look like:
[image: What it should appear on opening]

I've played around with the insert method on the table, the init method on the form, and some methods on the grid control but I can't seem to find a proper solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a property on the `DataSource` that is attached to the grid.  `InsertIfEmpty=No`.  See screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just a note, this is the same concept as in AX2012 and AX2009, so this isn't anything special about AX7.